# $\tan \theta =b/a$ then find the value of $a\cos2\theta+b\sin2\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

> Given $\tan \theta =b/a$, then find $a\cos2\theta+b\sin2\theta$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

I tried to solve the problem by first converting $\sin2\theta$ and $\cos2\theta$ in the $\tan$ terms (applying formula) and then simplifying it. But I did not get the *correct* answer, which is $a$.

Then I tried to substituting like this

$$a\cos2\theta + \tan\theta\sin2\theta.$$

I got a quadratic equation which I solved and substituted the values but failed to get the *correct* answer.

Comment: @TheGreatSeo I think that is $a \cdot \cos{2\theta}$, not $\arccos{2\theta}$.

Comment: you changed the question. -1

Comment: Looks *simple*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}a\cos2\theta+b\sin2\theta&=
a\ (\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)+b\ (2\sin\theta\cos\theta)\\&=
\cos^2\theta\ (a-a\tan^2\theta+2b\tan\theta)\\&=
\frac{a-a\tan^2\theta+2b\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}\\&=
a.\end{align}$$

Comment: Ohh thanks a lot finally understood:)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

You could use the tangent half-angle substitution (Weierstrass substitution). Using $t=\tan(\theta)$, you have $$\sin(2\theta)=\frac{2 t}{1+t^2}$$ $$\cos(2\theta)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: I tried that also please read my whole question. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere but finally I got

Comment: (a((a^2-b^2)+2a(b)^2)/a^2+b^2

Comment: Please show the working

Comment: Well : you know that $t=b/a$, I gave you $\sin(2\theta)$ and $\cos(2\theta)$ as functions of $t$. Just write your expression and replace.

Comment: Well I did that and I am getting the same

Comment: Are you getting the answer by this method for sure?

Comment: It is impossible for me to read your result (I am almost blind). The parentheses are unbalanced. Try to rewrite your result better.

Comment: Oh yes !! and it is very very very simple !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16101/discussion-between-user166748-and-claude-leibovici).

Comment: I must go now. Post your formula, please.

Comment: Wait a moment please

Comment: a*((a^2-b^2)/(a^2+b^2)) + (2a(b)^2)/(a^2+b^2)

Comment: I hope it is better

Comment: Is it similar to what you are getting?

Comment: Yes,your result is fine but it simplifies a lot. Put everything on the same denominator and expand and simplify. You are almost done.

Answer (score 0):

Assume, $\cos 2\theta+b\sin 2\theta=k$

$\implies 2b\sin \theta\cos\theta+a(\cos^2 \theta-sin^2\theta)=k$

$\implies 2b\tan \theta +a(1-tan^2\theta)=\large \frac {k}{cos^2\theta}$

$\implies 2b\tan \theta +a(1-tan^2\theta)={k}{sec^2\theta}$

$\implies 2b\tan \theta +a(1-tan^2\theta)={k}{(1+tan^2 \theta)}$

Now,substitute for $tan \theta=\frac{b}a$ and solve for $k$

Comment: It is much simpler if you use Weierstrass. Cheers :)

Comment: Where is the a?

Comment: Here in your question: $tan \theta=b/a$ then find the value of $cos2\theta+bsin2\theta$. :)

Comment: there is an a before cos2theta

Comment: It was not there previously when i took the job of solving it. You added it later. Or may be it was a mistake to Highlight a wrong question in the block. read my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $\tan \theta=b/a$ implies $(a,b)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. So 
$$a\cos 2\theta+b \sin 2\theta=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\cos\theta \cos 2\theta+\sin\theta \sin2\theta\right)$$ which we can simplify by use of an angle addition identity. The answer then follows directly.